# Convert @RequestParam to lower-case

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have many `@RequestParam` over many controllers that I need to enforce to be read as lower-case (e.g. `@RequestParam String email`). Is there an easier way other than going to each endpoint and setting the value of the parameter to the lower-case version?

What I tried is creating a Filter that passes a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which overrides `getParameter` and passes it down the chain, but I discovered that `@RequestParam` have nothing to do with `getParameter()`, maybe Spring uses reflection here?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want @RequestParameters to be case insensitive? Or do you want the values of request parameters to be converted to lower case?

Comment: @jetro157 I want the values to be lower-case, so whenever I use them it's guaranteed I'm dealing with the lower-case version. And only certain params, not all the params inside the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with the `@InitBinder` and `PropertyEditorSupport` provided for java beans. If I understand correctly, you want all the `@RequestParam` parameters to be lowercase. For this to achieve, I would declare my own `StringLowerCaseEditor` classs as below

```
public class StringLowerCaseEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport
{
    @Override
    public String getAsText()
    {
        return getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText( String text ) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        setValue( text.toLowerCase() );
    }
}
```

And then, within the `@Controller` class, a method can be used with the annotation `@InitBinder` which process all the request coming to this controller. From spring's doc about the annotation

> Such init-binder methods support all arguments that RequestMapping
>   supports, except for command/form objects and corresponding validation
>   result objects. Init-binder methods must not have a return value; they
>   are usually declared as void.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder( WebDataBinder dataBinder )
{
    StringLowerCaseEditor lowerCaseEditor = new StringLowerCaseEditor();
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor( String.class, lowerCaseEditor );
}
```

Or, to have a global impact, add the `@InitBinder Method` to `@ControllerAdvice` class. This will get executed on calling for every controller. You have the fine grained controll on the packages that needs this also via `@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "" )`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AllControllerAdvice
{
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder( WebDataBinder dataBinder )
    {
        StringLowerCaseEditor lowerCaseEditor = new StringLowerCaseEditor();
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor( String.class, lowerCaseEditor );
    }
}
```

If you want to process only a specific `@RequestParam`, you can use the `@InitBinder` with the expected param.

```
@InitBinder( "customerEmail" ) // Request param, can be comma separated
public void initBinder( WebDataBinder dataBinder )
{
    StringLowerCaseEditor lowerCaseEditor = new StringLowerCaseEditor();
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor( String.class, lowerCaseEditor );
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I don't want all the RequestParams to be lower-case, I only want certain ones to be. For example all endpoints that receive an email parameter should have the value in lower-case.. that way I guarantee all emails saved in the database are lowercase without having to lower-case them myself in each endpoint (db is just an example, even when I log the email I want it to be written in lower-case). Is that possible? Thank you

Comment: @prettyvoid I have updated my answer, please have a look